# gvim pid in $! different to wmctrl list

Tags: linux, vim, desktop

I have a script which launches multiple gvim windows. I want to position them in a certain way. `wmctrl` can do this, but because there are multiple instances, the window names are ambiguous. I figure: use pids.

```
gvim /tmp/xxx &

X=$!

wmctrl -lp | grep $X
echo $X
wmctrl -lp | grep GVIM
echo sleeping
sleep 3
wmctrl -lp | grep GVIM
```

The output is:

```
5211
sleeping
0x03400062  0 5218   localhost xxx (/tmp) - GVIM
```

It seems gvim starts out with pid 5211 but launches a new process for the actual window. Also, that process doesn't exist yet.

How can I unambiguously get the wmctrl window handle of the gvim instance I just started? Or should I use something else?

The `--echo-wid` option looks nice but I am using KDE.

Comment: You need to start gvim in foreground mode (`-f`). Also take a look at the `--echo-wid` option.

Comment: The first instance is `GVIM`, the second is `GVIM1` and so on.

Comment: There may be instances already running. I don't want to rely on strings like this, where's the proof it will always work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem, and solved it by running

```
gvim -f &
pid=$!
```

just as n.m. suggested in the comments above.

The manpage of gvim sais:

> ```
> -f          Foreground.   For  the  GUI  version, Vim will not fork and detach from the
>             shell it was started in.  On the Amiga, Vim is not restarted to open a  new
>             window.   This option should be used when Vim is executed by a program that
>             will wait for the edit session to finish (e.g. mail).   On  the  Amiga  the
>             ":sh" and ":!" commands will not work.
> ```

which explains why it works.

I don't know if you tried this, or if the answer even matters anymore, but I hate leaving a good question unanswered :)

credit goes to n.m. for pointing out the `-f` switch

Comment: Yeah thanks @n.m. sorry I overlooked your comment earlier :-/