# can't get stdout of gvim into a bash variable

Tags: bash, unix, vim

While trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16414347/gvim-pid-in-different-to-wmctrl-list) I'm experimenting with `gvim --echo-wid` which I think will work with `xdotool`.

Perhaps it's just brainache but I'm having a hell of a time getting the output of `gvim --echo-wid` into a bash variable **without blocking**.

```
X=`gvim --echo-wid`
```

doesn't work, the backtick capture seems to stop gvim from forking and detatching. `X` is only set after gvim terminates.

```
X=`gvim --echo-wid &`; echo "got: $X"
```

Same story.

```
mkfifo $F
(gvim --echo-wid > $F) &
X=`cat $F`
```

or

```
mkfifo $F
(gvim --echo-wid & > $F) &
X=`cat $F`
```

Same story.

I want

- gvim in the background
- its stdout in a bash variable, synchronously

or any other way I can get gvim's window ID for wmctrl or xdotool or some equivalent (without querying some list, I want to go directly to the window for THIS instance without string hacking).

Although at this point, I'm really just curious as to why capture isn't working. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

If it is outputting to stderr, you need to redirect it

```
X=`gvim --echo-wid 2>&1`
```

Comment: It still blocks until gvim terminates.

Answer (score 0):

When gvim launches it forks a new process for the gui and this can run in the background, but stdout isn't closed until the whole program closes.

If you pipe gvim into head, stdout will close and backtick will stop blocking.

```
X=`gvim --echo-wid | head -n 1`
echo "got $X"
```